# How Follow the Don't Repeat Yourself Principle When Consuming My Own Laravel API?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, rest

I'm developing a Laravel 4 app that will make the same CRUD operations on my data set available through a JSON REST API and a Web UI. It seems that to prevent breaking the DRY principle that my UI should consume my own API by routing all requests from the UI back to the API. I'm unsure though about the best approach to making this work. Presumably I would have separate UI and API controllers and somehow route the requests through. Or should I be looking at a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I'm actually tinkering with the same idea and it's pretty neat. With Laravel you do have the ability to make internal requests (some might refer to this as HMVC, but I won't). Here's the basics of an internal request.

```
$request = Request::create('/api/users/1', 'GET');

$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

`$response` will now contain the returned response of the API. Typically this will be returned a JSON encoded string which is great for clients, but not that great for an internal API request. You'll have to extend a few things here but basically the idea is to return the actual object back through for the internal call, and for external requests return the formatted JSON response. You can make use of things like `$response->getOriginalContent()` here for this kind of thing.

What you should look at doing is constructing some sort of internal `Dispatcher` that allows you to dispatch API requests and return the original object. The dispatcher should also handle malformed requests or bad responses and throw exceptions to match.

The idea itself is solid. But planning an API is hard work. I'd recommend you write up a good list of all your expected endpoints and draft a couple of API versions then select the best one.

Comment: Interesting, I was looking for documentation on this and couldn't find any initially. Realised this is actually inherited from Symfony

Comment: Yeah creating the initial request goes through the Symfony `HttpFoundation` component, but the dispatching of the request is done by the router.

Comment: you mention "original object", what are you actually referring to here?

Comment: Say for example your API returns a users info. On the web you want to see it as a JSON response and most likely you want to hide some columns, like password. Internally though it'd be better for you in the long run if it returned the original object (e.g., the Eloquent model) instead of getting it back in JSON. That way you can still interact with the object itself AND you still have all the columns in-tact.

Comment: You also need to consider that internal requests should by-pass any rate limiting or authentication. However, external requests would most likely be limited to 60 for unauthenticated requests and a few thousand or more for authenticated requests.

Comment: If you need some more ideas and brainstorming jump on #laravel on Freenode, someone is usually up for a good chat and I hang in there a bit. Cheers!

Comment: I can't see why it would hinder performance, but like anything it's something you should test thoroughly to ensure there are no bottlenecks.

Comment: @JasonLewis Maybe my mind is getting blocked here but does the request library actually give you back an eloquent object? I thought it would only be able to give you back data that would be produced by a client hitting the API, aka JSON? Also, for auth, I was just going to have an "admin" website username/password that would use the API, and everyone else their own credentials with limitations. The API wouldn't figure out it's the site by any dynamic means, only by its username. It's a solution but you think it's "clean?"

Comment: @JasonLewis This is just what I was looking for. But my celebrations ended with the limitation of setting custom headers. I have AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN which doesn't count in trusted headers of Symfony. Any insights?

Answer (score 34):

**NOTE: As vcardillo pointed out below, route filters are not called with these methods.**

I am currently doing the same thing, and Jason's answer got me going in a great direction. Looking at the [Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_create) documentation, I figured out how to POST, as well as everything else I'd need to do. Assuming you're using a form, here is some code that could help you:

GET:

```
$request = Request::create('/api/users/1', 'GET');

$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

POST:

```
$request = Request::create('/api/users/1', 'POST', Input::get());

$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

POST w/ cookies

```
$request = Request::create('/api/users/1', 'POST', Input::get(), Cookie::get('name'));

$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

POST w/ files

```
$request = Request::create('/api/users/1', 'POST', Input::get(), null, Input::file('file'));

$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

I hope this helps someone else. If you aren't using a form, or you are but not using Laravel's Input / Cookie facade, replace the Input / Cookie facades with your own content.

Comment: The only issue that I have seen with all of these, is that route filters are not called.

Comment: Link broken, updating: http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

Comment: This results in request timeout on the same api server :(

Answer (score 19):

Taylor Otwell [suggested](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5886) using `app()->handle()` rather than `Route::dispatch()` to achieve a clean request.

For `Route::dispatch($request)` I noticed if the endpoint of your non-GET request (parameters on the HTTP request body) uses a dependency injected `\Illuminate\Http\Request` or `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` extending instance, state of the parameters, cookies, files, etc. are from the *original* HTTP request. i.e., for your application's controller action method.

If parameter names and post method type for your app controller and API controller are the same, you won't notice the difference since the original parameter values are passed on. But when you're manually assembling the 3rd parameter of `Request::create()`, `Route::dispatch()` will result in it being ignored.

`app()->handle()` fixes that context problem in the Laravel request lifecycle.

**Caveat:** `app()->handle()` affects  `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request`, refreshing it with this new request instance. As a knock-on effect, calls like `Request::isXmlHttpRequest()` or `redirect()->back()` invoked after `app()->handle()` will cause unpredictable behaviour. I'd suggest tracking the context of your original request and instead use `redirect()->to(route('...'))` so you strictly control flow and state of your app.

Given all these corner cases, it may be best to just do a manual curl using a [Guzzle HTTP client](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

Comment: Guzzle HTTP for some reason hang the application when doing php artisan serve (work with my IIS justt fine). This app()->handle() save the day.

Comment: @GTHell it's been a year so maybe you already have figured it out but for others who may happen to come by this the reason is because php's built in server (which artisan serve uses) can only handle a single connection.

Comment: it could also be Guzzle and its issue with ports other than 80: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29017526/php-guzzle-5-cannot-handle-url-with-port-number-in-it

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for using passport login api internally, then you need to add the parameters to original request:

```
    protected function manualLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $request->request->add([
        'username' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $clientID,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'scope' => '*']);

    $newRequest = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'post');

    return Route::dispatch($newRequest)->getContent();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're consuming your own API, use `app()->handle()` instead of `Route::dispatch()` as Derek MacDonald has suggested.

`app()->handle()` creates a fresh request, while `Route::dispatch()` runs the route within the stack, effectively ignoring parameters that are part of the request that you're sending.

**Edit**: Just a heads-up. Taylor Otwell [advises against using sub-requests to make internal API calls, as they mess the current route](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5886#issuecomment-57627117). You can an HTTP API client like `Guzzle` instead to make the API calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Optimus API consumer](https://packagist.org/packages/optimus/api-consumer), the API is clean and simple, example making an internal request:

```
$response = app()->make('apiconsumer')->post('/oauth/token', $data);
```

In it's core, it uses `Illuminate\Routing\Router` and `Illuminate\Http\Request` to make the call

```
// create the request
$this->request->create($uri, $method, $data, [], [], $server, $content);

// get the response
$response = $this->router->prepareResponse($request, $this->app->handle($request));
```