# how to call route like new request

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I try to call my own api with laravel I tried all the options like:
in the answers:
[Consuming my own Laravel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api)

or in this blog:
http://blog.antoine-augusti.fr/2014/04/laravel-calling-your-api/

and this plugin:
https://github.com/teepluss/laravel4-hmvc

sorry for sound dumb I dont understand all the things but they not make full 100% real request like
for example with normal ajax post request i can do this to get some parameter:

`Request::createFromGlobals()->request->get('some-parameter')`

but with the others techniqe this just return null
I am using this way becase thats the way how "thephpleague/oauth2-server" plugin get the post parametrs
( https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/blob/master/src/AuthorizationServer.php#L234 )

so my question: is there a real way to call other route and to make it 100% look like normal request?

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like you are trying to do you could use [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) or cURL to make actual calls.

The real question is why do these need to be actual calls? The first link you posted has some really great examples that would work well for any calls that go directly back to your Laravel application. That article linked to a module called [HMVC](https://github.com/teepluss/laravel4-hmvc) which keeps your code looking neat and simplifies the process.

Comment: thanks like I said i am using oauth2 server plugin that for getting the post paramertrs using this code: Request::createFromGlobals()->request->get('some-parameter'), I tryied the first link and the hmvc plugin they all not setting the Request::createFromGlobals()->request->get('some-parameter') parameters

Comment: cURL or Snoopy will absolutely do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Any HTTP Client will do this.

- [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/)
- [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz)
- [Requests](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/)