# Api and web application in the same project

Tags: php, web-services, api, laravel-4, cross-domain

#### EDIT:

I took the route of separating Api and Web Application. However, the issue with cross-site requests remains. The question below this edit is kind of irrelevant now, except for the fact that the cross-site request issue remains. I will leave the question below for reference and maybe to help others decide what to do in this situation.

#### /EDIT

I recently started work on a web application and with the intent to develop mobile applications as well, I figured I would like to create a public API. Here are some of the challenges I have encountered:

The API is actually served from a subdomain (api.example.com) which is a problem because I cannot make cross site requests. The only solution I came up with is to add routes for both `api.example.com` and the non-API routes so that I can make calls without cross-site requests which would actually introduce a lot of redundancies and that is not the route I would like to go (no pun intended).

Here is a little snippet that sets up the routes for the API (I use the Laravel framework):

```
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('globals.API_URL_RAW'), 
              'namespace' => 'MySite\Api\v1', 
              'prefix' => 'v1'], function(){

    Route::post('/register', 'RegistrationController@store');

}
```

So, as you can see, I have routes that respond to requests from `api.example.com/v1/register` for example. In the web app I use ajax to access this API, but access to the API is restricted due to cross-site requests.

**The go-to solution would probably be to separate the web app and the api completely, but how would I then go about solving the cross-site requests issue ?**

> > No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Also, if I were to separate the API from the web application, I would have to handle the JSON in my web application (the API returns JSON objects) whereas now I can just work with the actual objects.

I am very new to developing Web apis, and I feel like I am not getting something here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### EDIT:

There is actually a very similar question that tackles the same problem, which can be found here:

> > [Consuming my own Laravel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api?rq=1)

However I think cross-site requests issue is not an issue for the questioner, because his API is served from the same domain.