# How to redirect user invoking a function in contoller Class? - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want user to get calculated result. I had to redirect `localhost:8000/question/33`  to `localhost:8000/caclulate/some_payload`
I have no idea how to do this.

```
class QuestionController extends Controller

public function index($id)

if(question->id == 33)
    #Here I want to invoke calculate($payload)

    return view('quiz.index', [
        'payload' => $payload,
        'question' => $question,
        ]);
}
public function calculate($payload)
{

    return view('quiz.result', [
...
        ]);
}
```

I've tried `$this->calculate($payload)` and `calculate()`.

Comment: Where is $payload set? Does your controller class have access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want call controller method from another controller method. 
You could try it this way:

```
$request = Request::create('calculate/some_payload', 'GET', $params);
return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

For more info see Jason Lewis answer here: [Consuming my own Laravel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api)

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting Request::json () to provide form input? Or, are you looking for Input::all() form input?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved, my problem with:

```
return Redirect::action('QuestionController@calculate', 
array('payload' => $payload));
```

But it generates address with parameter

```
http://localhost:8000/calculate?payload=%242y%2410%24V1OqC7rwp1w1rPXYQ42lRO9lJYQvmXB3nScw6D0EVeFR7VUz0QyCS
```

And I want to use`$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, so I need to invoke method with `$_POST` and catch `$payload` in method calculate. How can I do this?