# How to retrieve JSON from a API endpoint using Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I have 2 projects made with Laravel 5.4:

1. Prj-1 it is an Restful API that returns JSON.
2. Prj-2 it is an website that consumes the above endpoints.

In this way, I have the follow endpoint from Prj-1 :
**myAPI.com/city** that returns a list of all cities in the database in a **JSON** format.

Inside Prj-2 I have the follow:

```
Route:
Route::get('/showCityAPItest','AddressController@getcity'); 

Controller:
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
...
public function getcity()
    {


        $request =Request::create('http://myAPI.com/city', 'GET');
        $response = Route::dispatch($request);
        dd($response);
    }
```

If I use directly the URL (http://myAPI.com/city) in the browser, it works. I can see the JSON as expected.
BUt when I try to retrieve it from the Prj-2 I can't see it in the browser.

Actually I see

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.10.1 (Ubuntu)
```

I was following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api) but I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, @Joel Hinz is right. Request will work within same project api end. 
You need to use GuzzleHttp.
Step 1. Install guzzle using composer. Windows base operating guzzle command for composer  :

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

step 2 write following code

```
public function getcity()
    {     
       $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
       $data =$client->request('GET', 'http://myAPI.com/city', [
       'headers' => [
           'Accept'     => 'application/json',
           'Content-type' => 'application/json'
       ]
       ]);

       $x = json_decode($data->getBody()->getContents());
       return response()->json(['msg' => $x], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to which you are referring is talking about *internal* routes. You can't use the `Request` and `Route` facades for external addresses like that. Instead, use e.g. Guzzle (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) to send your requests from the second site.