# Laravel: How to get the json response from API

Tags: php, laravel

This is the response returned from one of my controllers

```
    class initController extends Controller
    {

        public function index(Request $request)
        {

            $init=DB::table('inits')->select('authID')->inRandomOrder()->first();
            if($init == false){
                return response()->json(['status:' => 1 ,'authID' => current($init)]);
            }
            return response()->json(['status:' => 0 ,'authID' => current($init)]);
        }

    }
```

This is the API route

```
    Route::get('init', 'initController@index');
    Route::get('getLargeImage', 'getLargeImageController@getImg');
```

This is the getLargeImage contoller

```
class getLargeImageController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {

    }

}
```

Now, in this controller how can I  get the json response from the first one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consuming my own Laravel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api)

Comment: This is not how controllers are meant to be used. You are most likely looking for some sort of service class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
class getLargeImageController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
       $response = app('App\Http\Controllers\initController')->index($request);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, don't understand how to use this.

Comment: got this error Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\initController::index(), 0 passed in /home/jonnyy/PhpstormProjects/zcapt/app/Http/Controllers/getLargeImageController.php on line 20 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: @hostJ I am really sorry. You should pass the request. Updated plz check

Comment: Goodluck... Cheers

Comment: One more question, how can I transfer this json response to an array or get a value in it, because the $response returned a lot of objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple Google search would suffice; https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/internal-requests

There are many articles on making internal requests on Laravel, and also, this question has been asked and answered previously here, e.g; [Consuming my own Laravel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api)

To answer your question, you make an internal request base on your route;

```
$request = Request::create('init', 'GET');
$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

Comment: how to implement this, I put in my getlargeImage controller and dd($response) it returns an error which is Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Route' not found

Comment: if it is not found, put it in via `use App\Http\Controllers\Route;` at the top of your file where all dependencies are included

Comment: I tried but still not work, seems like the Route::dispatch instance is not recommended in the latest ver(5.7), they prefer   'app()->handle()' method which you mentioned in the [consuming-my-own-laravel-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api)