# How to post and receive data on my Laravel API with Guzzle

Tags: laravel, api, request, guzzle

I have a very awkward issue here:

I am trying to call my own Laravel API like this:

```
$api_url    `enter code here`=  env("API_URL")."login";
$data=  json_encode($data);
$api_url    =   env("API_URL")."login";
$client     =   new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$headers    =   array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' => csrf_token());
$response   =   $client->request('POST', $api_url , ['headers'=>$headers,'json' => $data]);
print_r($response);
```

Then my API end point has code like this:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
//This line gives me NULL
dump($request->all());

//the lines below print this "{"email":"dev@gumption.pk","password":"password01"}"
//but I cannot get this POSTED data in variables even with $request->input('email')
$content = $request->getContent();
print_r($content);
```

}

I am NOT able to retrieve variables from this POSTED data. I have tried $request->input('email');
$request->json('email');

Nothing is working. It simply says NULL.

I am not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consuming my own Laravel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520691/consuming-my-own-laravel-api)

Comment: You can't get json data using `$request->input(x)` you need to use `$request->json(x)`

Comment: this is NOT even working with $request->json(x);

In fact nothing is working for me on it. It is only showing some output with this code:
$content = $request->getContent();
print_r($content);

it prints following output:
"{"email":"dev@gumption.pk","password":"password01"}"


but I cannot get this POSTED data in variables even with JSON_DECODE or anything else. It is only print_r() function that shows this output. var_dump() return NULL, dump() && dd() in Laravel are returning NULL as well.

Comment: Don't use the env helper outside of your config files, you will not be able to cache your config. Why are you using a csrf_token for your API? What are the contents of the $data variable?

Comment: This was the last option that may be token is missing or something like that. But simple is that it is not allowing me to get the contents posted on the API end point.